# Binding CheckBox multiple conditions for data trigger in WPF?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, data-binding, multidatatrigger

I have a problem with binding CheckBox to multiple conditions for data trigger.
I'm trying to change the background of DataGridRow with two conditions.

First - CheckBox IsChecked.

Second - DataGridCell value is 1.

Here is my code

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkTehnickaPodrska" Content="Oboj tikete kojima je istekla teh. podrška" Margin="5" IsChecked="True"/>

<Style.Triggers>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkTehnickaPodrska}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding [Istekla tehnička podrška]}" Value="1"/>
          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is there any error, unexpected behaviour? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Project builds all but not showing any errors. Problem is that not change the background of DataGridRow. I'm not sure where I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use a converter in your second conditional binding:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CellValueConverter}}" Value="1"/>
```

And handle your bound data in the converter.